# How to print the first letter of an element in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pyscripter

Currently,I am doing a project where I am creating a music quiz. I have created an external CSV file called playlist.csv where I have stored the song and artist. I have already imported the CSV file, but I need to print the first letter of the song from the external file in Pyscripter - and I can't work out how to do this.

Comment: Post the sample csv

Comment: Just as @RahulAgarwal suggests, please provide some sample data of your CSV as well as the your code where you try to solve the problem. Please check out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for how to format your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('playlist.csv') as mycsv:
    print(mycsv.readline()[0])
```

Comment: This is my table: Song | Artist
-------------------------
 No Tears Left to Cry | Adriana Grade
 I Like It | Cardi B  
 Marroon 5 Girls Like You | Andrea Garcia    
 God's Plan | Drake          
 The Middle |  Marren Morris     
 Back to You | Selena Gomez      
 Make Me Feel | Janelle Monae       
 In My Feelings | Drake   
 All The Stars | Kendrick Lemar         
This is America | Childish Gambino        
One Kiss | Dua Lipa
Psycho | Post Malone

Comment: What I am looking to do is, from the CSV file above, print the first letter of the song name - which someone has already answered. I am also looking to print the artist of the song. Is there a way I can concatenate this using print()?